# Crypto.HashPassword and VerifyHashedPassword

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, cryptography, helper

As titled, I'm using MVC 3 helper Crypto to hash my password, then i save nothing except encrypted password into database.

When I implement the login form, I make a boolean function, retrieve password stored in database 
and get the boolean result with this helper:

```
Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(password in DB, password in login form)
if true, then login
if false, the display "password wrong"
```

This few day, I was trying to test my login function. I found one fact: If a new registrar comes to register at the system, the previous user will be failed to login, displaying "password wrong".

Is there any problem with my program or did I miss something?

```
Function to return bool
if (Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword(parent.Password, password))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ModelState.AddModelError("", "You was input password wrongly!");
                            return false;
                        }



Code to hash and store the password
parent.Password = Crypto.HashPassword(parent.Password);
                        peoplemanager.Add(parent);
```

Comment: Your question looks like a poem ... but it does not rhyme.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about ASP.NET, I was just amused about the form of your question.

Comment: From your description, it looks like you store only one hashed password for all the users, and overwrite it when a new user signs in. Show the database access code.

Comment: no, each user has a row to store hashed password

Comment: Minor security quibble.  Display "username or password wrong." when either the username or the password is incorrect.  Specifying one or the other gives extra information to any attacker.

Comment: i didn't change anything to previous record in DB

Comment: How did you resolve this? I have run into the same problem. This stops working after a while.

Comment: Are you entering the password each time you log in or are you letting the browser auto-fill the password? I would debug and check your password form entry to verify that it's the password you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to follow this Tutorial I found it very helpful when creating my membership solution:

http://theintegrity.co.uk/2010/12/asp-net-mvc-2-custom-membership-provider-tutorial-part-3/